# Getting Error when trying to crawl my spider (NotImplementedError)

Tags: python, asp.net, scrapy, syntax-error

My Scrapy code doesn't work. I'm trying to do scraping of the forum but receiving an error.
Here is my code:

```
import scrapy, time

class ForumSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'forum_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['visforvoltage.org/latest_tech/']
    start_urls = ['http://visforvoltage.org/latest_tech//']

def parse_urls(self, response):
   for href in response.css(r"tbody a[href*='/forum/']::attr(href)").extract():
       url = response.urljoin(href)
       print(url)
       req = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_data)
       time.sleep(10)
       yield req

def parse_data(self, response):
    for sel in response.css('html').extract():
       data = {}
       data['name'] = response.css(r"div[class='author-pane-line author-name'] span[class='username']::text").extract()
       data['date'] = response.css(r"div[class='forum-posted-on']:contains('-') ::text").extract()
       data['title'] = response.css(r"div[class='section'] h1[class='title']::text").extract()
       data['body'] = response.css(r"div[class='field-items'] p::text").extract()
       yield data
   

    next_page = response.css(r"li[class='pager-next'] a[href*='page=']::attr(href)").extract()
    if next_page:
        yield scrapy.Request(
            response.urljoin(next_page),
            callback=self.parse_urls)
```

Here is an error:

```
[scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://visforvoltage.org/latest_tech> (referer: None)
raise NotImplementedError('{}.parse callback is not defined'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
NotImplementedError: ForumSpiderSpider.parse callback is not defined
```

I will really appreciate if somebody can help me with it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent class `scrapy.Spider` has a method called `start_requests`. That is the method that will check your `start_urls` and create the first requests for the spider.

That method expects you to have a method called `parse` to work as a callback function. So the quickest way to solve the problem is changing your `parse_urls` method to `parse`, like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
   for href in response.css(r"tbody a[href*='/forum/']::attr(href)").extract():
       url = response.urljoin(href)
       print(url)
       req = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_data)
       time.sleep(10)
       yield req
```

If you want to change that behavior, you need to overwrite the `start_requests` method in your class, so you can determine the name of the  callback function. **For example:**

```
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_urls, dont_filter=True)
```